# Terraform - Preserving State of Different Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I have the following scenario. I have 5 users that use the same Linux machine to provision resources on AWS cloud via Terraform.
Each user "ssh" in the same Linux machine with same username/password - create its terraform configuration - run it.
How do I ensure that each user configuration is isoloted from the other user e.g
When user run the terraform command e.g apply, plan, destroy - only configuration related to him should be displayed, executed and deleted.
I can not provision a separate linux machine for each user at this stage.

thanks for support

Comment: User accounts should never be shared. If you're ever in a situation where you're giving out the same user password or private key to multiple people, you should step back and rethink your approach.

Comment: I agree with jordanm that this requirement seems quite unusual... could you instead give each of your users a separate user account on this shared Linux machine, so that they can each work independently in their own home directories? That way they can still share any software preinstalled on the system but will each have their own private home directory to develop configurations within.